# Skip the execution of trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement, wherein I have to skip the execution of trigger on Task after update operation on Task from Case.
On update of case fields, am performing an update operation on Task Object.
This fires Task triggers and LastModified by gets changed for all the Task records which are related to Case Object.

My intent is to skip the execution of TaskTriggerHandler method, only for this particular update operation when it happens on the case. 
Is it possible, if yes, please let me know....

Answer (score 7):

You can implement that logic by yourself.

You can write an UtilClass to check if you execute or not the Trigger Logic

```
public class ByPassUtils {

    public static Map<String,Boolean> triggerNameBypassed = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    
    public static void ByPass(String triggerName){
        triggerNameBypassed.put(triggerName,true);
    }
    
    public static void UndoByPass(String triggerName){
        triggerNameBypassed.put(triggerName,false);
    }
    
    public static Boolean isByPassed(String triggerName){
        return triggerNameBypassed.containsKey(triggerName) && triggerNameBypassed.get(triggerName);
    }
}
```

logic  when you want to bypass (maybe in the case trigger for your example)

```
ByPassUtils.ByPass('TaskAfterUpdate');
```

in your trigger code (in your case TaskAfterUpdate)

```
if(!ByPassUtils.isByPassed('TaskAfterUpdate')){
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There an easy practical way to do something like this

In your Task trigger add something like this

```
public class TriggerControl {
    public static Boolean isComingFromCase = false;
}

trigger TaskTrigger on Task (..all your before/afters) {

  public void MyTriggerMethod(...your params) {
    if (TriggerControl.isCallingFromCase) {
      return;
    }

    ...rest of your code
  }


}
```

Then, on whatever method you want to skip the triggers you can do

```
...code

TriggerControl.isComingFromCase = true;

...more code
```

If you set that variable to true before you perform the update that kicks off the Task Trigger then the methods for which you added the `if` statement won't be executed.

Comment: At least *mention* handler pattern! :P

Comment: You just did. :)

Comment: @SebastianKessel, of what type is an apex trigger? I'm trying to utilize this to skip a case trigger, but am receiving an invalid type error when I try to create an instance of the apex trigger and without creating it I am receiving a variable does not exist error without it.

Comment: It’s a trigger. You can’t create it dynamically. Also, its methods are static so there is no need for an instance of the class.

Comment: Just saw my code has a typo. You need to add “Boolean” to the variable definition.

Comment: @SebastianKessel, my issue is in the method of the controller I'm trying to set the variable in. In my case the trigger name is CaseTrigger, and         CaseTrigger.isComingFromEmail = true; is resulting in a variable does not exist CaseTrigger error which is why I thought I had to initialize it.

Comment: I’m not sure what the error could be. If you updated your code with my recent correction and it still doesn’t work then I’d open another question. You should reference this one so it doesn’t get closed as a dupe.

Comment: @S.B. I noticed that in your new question you found a problem with my original answer. I've updated my code to reflect the fix to the problem

Answer (score 2):

When you are updating a particular field on case you update a particular field on task which fires another trigger on Task object to update the last modified by.

You can put condition on particular field.

```
If(Case.someFieldValue == 'someValue'){

//Then only update the task field.

}
```