# Variable does not Exist: CaseTrigger

Tags: apex, trigger, type

I'm trying to pass a value to a variable in an apex trigger from an apex controller in an effort to control whether the the code in the trigger is executed.

In myController initialization, I try to set this variable:

**Controller:**

```
public myController() {

        CaseTrigger.isComingFromEmail = true; 

}
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert){

    public static boolean isComingFromEmail = false;

    if (isComingFromEmail) {
        return;
    }
    else {
//Actual Processing Here
}
```

The error received on myController:

> Variable does not exist: CaseTrigger

**Related post:**

[Skip the execution of trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133541/skip-the-execution-of-trigger#133552)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triggers are not classes, and you shouldn't reference them like this. You should create a separate class to store your static variable, and then reference this class in both your controller and trigger.

Comment: To confirm, in the related post the recommendation by Sebastian is not valid?

Comment: I don't think so. But it does illustrates the pattern. I'd prefer Akram G's solution instead, since you can reuse it on other triggers latter as well.

Comment: Mihai Neagoe's post on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61371/static-variables-defined-in-a-trigger is also a good example of the pattern that Sebastian tries to illustrate.